# Как вычислить время по углу эклиптики

Tags: математика, тригонометрия

Правлю код одного астрологического сайта, и забуксовал на одном момент =). Ибо не то, что в астрологии, но и в астрономии я полный ноль.
Задача такая. Есть натальная карта (она же сфера эклиптики). Соответственно, 360 градусов соответствуют 24 часам. Но движение солнца происходит не равномерно. И как мне узнать, например, какой сдвиг по времени, например, в 190 градсах? В интернете нигде не могу найти формулу для рассчета. Спасибо.

Comment: движение Солнца по небесной сфере неравномерно, а продолжительность дня и ночи меняется на всем протяжении. Для удобства решили взять 24ч как среднее по году. Простое деление 360 градусов на 24 часа не даст точного результата.

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал использовать календарь или астрономическую программу, для того, чтобы узнать сдвиг времени по градусам натальной карты, которая учитывает неравномерное движение солнца и специфические характеристики каждого местоположения

Comment: 360 градусов соответствуют 24 часам, так что каждый градус соответствует 24/360 = 1/15 часа.
получается, сдвиг в часах = (градусы / 360) * 24. для 190 градусов: сдвиг в часах = (190 / 360) * 24 = XX часов

Comment: Это длинная и большая тема. Рекомендую книги https://alexbelousov.sk/astro/daffet-smit.pdf или http://xn--b1aph9d.xn--p1ai/biblioteka/cartochki/0020.htm. Там достаточно простое изложение основ.

Comment: Senior Pomidor, а какую программу рекомендуете? С учетом того, что мне надо скриптом в автоматическом режиме получать данные. Сейчас для рассчетов используется swetest, но она, походу, не умеет так дельту считать.

Comment: @anagamin я не могу подсказать. непонятно где и как нужно использовать. я думаю, что можно легко нагуглить что вы хотите